# Ideals generated by regular sequences

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, lie-groups, homological-algebra, cohomology, homological-dimension

In Vasconcelos' paper ([Ideals generated by R-sequences](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82227314.pdf)), he proved

> If $R$ is a local ring, $I$ an ideal of finite projective dimension, and $I/I^2$ is a free $R/I$ module, then $I$ can be generated by a regular sequence.

This is a theorem for local ring.

In Kac's paper, ([Torsion in cohomology of compact Lie groups and Chow rings of reductive algebraic groups](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01388548)), he referred this result (in appendix, Proof of Theorem 1), but used for non-local ring.

More precisely, he constructed a map for a compact lie group $K$, and a field $k$, 
$S(M)\stackrel{\psi}\to H^\bullet(K/T;k)$, where $M=L\otimes k$ with $L$ the weight lattice, and $T$ the maximal torus. He claim $\ker \psi$ is generated by a homogenous regular sequence.

Furthermore, what I believe to be right, is the following

> For polynomial ring  $R$ over field, and a graded ideal $I$ such that $I/I^2$ is free over $R/I$ (as graded module), then $I$ is generated by a homogenous regular sequences.

**My question is, how to prove this if it is true? If not, is the $\ker \psi$ in the paper generated by a regular sequence?**

Maybe some useful remarks,

1. This is not true for example $k[x]/x^2$, and $I=(x)$. Since $k[x]/x=k$ never admits a finite projective(=free since local) $k[x]/x^2$ resolution by dimension argument.
2. When the ring is local and $I$ is the maximal ideal, this is exactly the theorem of regular local ring. I tried to move the proof, but fails, because of the above example.
3. The main step of Vasconcelos' paper, is to a result due to auslander and buchbaum. It discussed local ring specifically.
4. Generally, there is a concept called [regular ideal](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07CU), but it is local.
5. I do not even know whether we can pick the sequence to be arbitary choice of representative of basis.
6. I also wounder whether it is true for all graded ring with $I$ of finite projective dimension.
7. For $\psi$, it is more crutial when the field of positive characteristic. When it is of characteristic zero, the $\psi$ is nothing but the classical thing, the projection to coinvariant algebra.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure even your (6) is correct, but am a bit lazy today to check things carefully, so let me answer your question for polynomial rings.

If $I\subset R$, a graded ideal, it is immediate that one can pick a minimal set of generators for $I$ which are homogeneous. With your hypothesis, these become a regular sequence after localizing at the `irrelevant' maximal ideal by Vasconcelos.

Let $x_1,\ldots, x_k$ be the homogeneous generators of $I$. If they were not a regular sequence, say $x_1,\ldots x_l$ are, but $x_{l+1}$ is a zero divisor modulo $x_1,\ldots,x_l$. Then, $x_{l+1}$ is contained in an associated prime of $(x_1,\ldots,x_l)$, but this ideal is graded and thus so are all its associated primes. In particular, the associated prime containing $x_{l+1}$ is graded. This prime is contained in the irrelevant maximal ideal and thus survives when you localize. But, this says that $x_1,\ldots, x_{l+1}$ do not form a regular sequence after localizing, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I found the right reference, and read them and carry them properly to graded case.

The main lemma is [Auslander-Buchsbaum](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/090V)'s argument

> Let $R$ be a **noetherian ring**, 
>   $M$ a **finitely generated** module. Assume $M$ admit a **finite finitely generated free resolution**.
>   Then if the annihilator of $M$ is not trivial, then it contains a nonzero divisor in $R$.

The sketch of the proof is as the following.

1. Firstly, show that $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is free for any associaed prime $\mathfrak{p}$ of $R$. This is essentially the main process of [Auslander-Buchsbaum equality](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/090U), but one can use matrix coefficient trick to prove it directly. 
   --- Here we use the assumption that $R$ is noetherian.
2. But the annihilator $\mathfrak{a}$ kills $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$, so $\mathfrak{a}_{\mathfrak{p}}=0$ or $M_{\mathfrak{p}}=0$. 
   Since the rank to get the rank of $M_{\mathfrak{p}}$ does not depend on $\mathfrak{p}$. 
   --- Here we use the assumption of finiteness of free resolution.
3. But if $\mathfrak{a}_{\mathfrak{p}}=0$, then the annihilator of $\mathfrak{a}$ is not contained in any prime associated to $R$, so their union, the zero divisor. Thus $\mathfrak{a}=0$. 
   --- Here we use the assumption that $R$ is noetherian.
4. So $M_{\mathfrak{p}}=0$, then then the annihilator of $\mathfrak{a}$ is not contained in any prime associated to $R$, so their union, the zero divisor. 
   --- Here we use the assumption that $M$ is finitely generated.

So we are done.

> For a polynomial ring $R$ over field,
>   the homogenous ideal $I$ is generated by a regular sequence of homogenous elements if $I/I^2$ is free over $R/I$.

The sketch of the proof is. the following.

1. Note that $I$ admits a finite finitely generated free (twisted) resolution due to [Quillen–Suslin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quillen%E2%80%93Suslin_theorem). 
   --- Since we only need an existence, maybe the one who do not want to use such big theorem can use only Scheja-Stroch's computational proof of Hilbert’s syzygy theorem (for example, Weibel page 114).
2. As the annihilator of $R/I$, it consists some non zero divisor. So is $I\setminus R_+ I$ by [(strong) prime avoidance](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00DS) and the fact $I\neq R_+I$.
3. Pick such nonzero divisor $x\in I\setminus R_+ I$, then consider $\overline{R}=R/xR$, and $\overline{I}$ the image of $I$.
4. It is clear, now $\overline{I}/\overline{I}^2=I/(I^2+xR)$ is free of less rank than $\overline{R}/\overline{I}=R/I$. 
   --- Here we use that it is over some field, and graded, otherwise, one cannot claim like this, since $x$ may not extend to a basis of $I/I^2$ over $R/I$.
5. $\overline{I}$ admits a finite finitely generated free (twisted) resolution. 
   --- remind the prove $pd_R M=pd_{R/xR} M/xM$ for non zero divisor $x$ for both $R$ and $M$.

Then it follows from induction.

The above process follows for neotherian local ring, as done in [Ideals generated by R-sequences](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82227314.pdf).

But it is also not clear what will happen for general graded ring.

---

Edit: My classmate remind me that this is also true.

> Let $R$ be a **connected noetherian ring**, 
>   $M$ a **finitely generated** module. Then if the annihilator of $M$ is not trivial, then it contains a nonzero divisor in $R$.

By the same way. So we also have this

> For a connected graded ring $R$ over field $k$ with $R^0=k$, only nonnegative degree, 
>   a homogenous ideal $I$ is generated by a regular sequence of homogenous elements if $I/I^2$ is free over $R/I$ and $I$ has finite projective dimension.

Besides, for any set of element presenting a basis, by our choice, our choice of regular sequence presents a set of basis of $I/I^2$ over $R/I$, so it differs by our choice a invertible matrix. Then it reduces to exchange two element. We permute them by degree reason. So in conclusion

> In above case, any set of basis presenting a set of basis for $I/I^2$ over $R/I$ forms a regular sequence.